# Can GDB debug C++ lambdas?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, gdb

I use C++ 11 features actively. I have program created in Visual Studio 2013 that relies on lambdas to run multiple threads (lambda represents task, and thread receives lambda instance that it has to run). Lambda is defined in static library and linked in executable file that calls it from thread created by this executable file.
When I try to debug Linux version of this application with GDB, it looks like GDB can not step into method that contains lambda. It can not set breakpoints in this function, and when I try to step into, it even steps in methods that lambda calls from its body, but after `return` from these methods it doesn't go to lambda body, it goes to next method that lambda calls, etc.
Are there any way to debug lambdas body with GDB?

Comment: What do you mean by "method", here? The term is not well-defined in C++.

Comment: I mean non-static object member function when say `method`.

Comment: Just tested, gdb (GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1) can step inside lambda correctly. which version of GDB do you use ? Do you compile with optimization, symbol stripped ?

Comment: I use GBD included with CentOS 6.5, I think it is v7.2. I think this is problem, but not lambda one; I have file `functions.cpp` in library, and file `functions.cpp` in application. It looks like GDB can not work when static library and executable built with this static library have source file with exactly the same name. It looks like it tries to use `functions.cpp` from executable file when it has to use `functions.cpp` from library. So, the problem is not in lambda.

Comment: That sounds like an unlikely bug for gdb to have.  Ordinarily when there are problems it is something simple like forgetting to use -g.  You can check this by examining the object files with readelf.  The next most common source of problems like this is if the compiler emits bad debuginfo; but that requires more digging to find out.

Comment: may be this will thread will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418035/any-luck-debugging-lambdas-with-gdb

Answer (score 9):

I've seen them in stack traces before, so it does at least know about them. I've never tried setting a normal breakpoint in one. It's sort of a hack, but you can set a breakpoint in one (or anywhere) by using `asm volatile("int $3");` on x86(-64).

Here's an example program:

```
int main(){
    auto f = [](){
        asm volatile("int $3");
    };
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's it's backtrace when it hits that breakpoint:

```
#0  0x0000000000400577 in main::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const ()
#1  0x000000000040058d in main ()
```

Comment: You can use `DebugBreak()` or `__debugbreak()` with MIcrosoft Visual C++. This is the only way I know to break in lambda functions on ARM with MSVC2012; Microsoft compilers do not support inline assembly on the ARM and x64 processors.

Comment: I've never done it but for x64/ARM I think you can create an assembler / S file which you compile with your project, which defines a function and custom assembly. Then you just call your assembly function. (can you inline those function calls?).

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, gdb cannot step into lambdas -- it just skips over them. Not only that, stepping into a lambda definition seems to confuse gdb and it proceeds to the end of the current function. You can, however, place a breakpoint explicitly inside a lambda, and if you hit that point, you will stop. This is obviously far from ideal.

Comment: The lambda was probably optimized and inlined. Have you turned off optimization? (-O0)